# Is there a law establishing the procedure by which a U.S. senator resigns?

Tags: us-senate

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/the-law-on-addressees-of-u-s-senators-resignations) on politics.stackexchange.com isn't getting any answers, so I'll try a similar question here.

- Is there some statute or provision of the Constitution of the United States or case law saying that the way a U.S. senator resigns is by submitting a letter of resignation to the **governor** of the state that the senator represents, rather than to some other person such as the president of the senate (who is also the vice-president of the United States) or other federal officer?
- Is that considered the proper way to do it **only** because someone set a precedent and others follow precedent?  If so, when was the precedent set?  And might it be considered law if there is no Constitutional provision or statute or case law?

Comment: Tangentially, I believe that when Nixon resigned the Presidency, there was considerable debate over to whom he should submit the letter, as there was neither law nor precedent to guide. Somehow it was decided the Secretary of State would be best, and now there is a precedent.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Here I thought that was covered in the 25th Amendment.  But it appears that it is not.

Comment: Since posting this question, I have received an email from someone working in the office of the historian of the Senate saying that there have been some cases in which the president of the Senate was the addressee.  But still no word on whether some authority ordained these practices.

Answer (score 2):

Article I, Section 5 of the Constitution specifies that

> Each House shall be the Judge of the Elections, Returns and Qualifications of its own Members, and a Majority of each shall constitute a Quorum to do Business; but a smaller Number may adjourn from day to day, and may be authorized to compel the Attendance of absent Members, in such Manner, and under such Penalties as each House may provide.
>
> Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two thirds, expel a Member.

It therefore seems likely that if there is any procedure specified for the resignation of a senator, it is specified in the Senate rules.  Since Senate rules are passed by the Senate only, not being voted on by the House of Representatives nor presented to the President for his signature, they are not laws.

My quick perusal of the rules, however, did not find anything.

Comment: Are you sure they are not laws? As an administrative rule made under a power granted by the Constitution I am pretty sure they would qualify as administrative laws.

Comment: House rules are binding only within the House, and are not laws.

Comment: @DaleM a law is a bill passed by both houses, after having been signed by the president or vetoed and then overridden.  The houses' rules are passed by each house, respectively as the manifestation of their constitutional power of self government.  As I understand it, administrative law is that governing the functioning of various government agencies, and like all laws must pass both houses, etc.  The rules are an implementation detail, essentially, of Art. I Sec. 5.

Comment: @phoog No, "law" is what can be ruled on by a court. Many tenants of common law have never passed through a legislature anywhere in the world. The question is, if there were such a rule and it was not followed, could the Supreme Court intervene?

Comment: @DaleM The way I understand this is that these rules are created by the houses, and not assented to by the president or passed by the other house. As far as I know, the US Judiciary is not empowered to review the rules and procedures of congress, or to make decisions on alleged breaches of those rules and procedures. Congress is constitutionally empowered to discipline its members.

Comment: @jimsug Which begs the question: if they are enforceable (by the house) with sanctions, does this not make them laws?

Comment: @DaleM It really depends on your definition of [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_procedure). It's binding on its members, and certain provisions are binding on members of the public (for instance, parliaments can often compel witnesses to provide evidence to a committee or inquest). But many things are binding only on members - company constitutions, for instance - and that doesn't necessarily make them law. I would not call parliamentary procedure _law_, although it is called _parliamentary law_ sometimes - nor have I ever head it referred to as _law_ without the category.

Comment: @dale All that said, I don't believe the SCOTUS has the power to review and discipline breaches of parliamentary procedure. So by your definition, it wouldn't be law.

Comment: @DaleM no, the Supreme Court cannot enforce the rules of a house of Congress.  "Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two thirds, expel a Member."  This means that each house is its own sole authority with respect to its rules.  It reminds me somewhat of parliamentary sovereignty in the UK, except of course the scope is each house itself instead of the entire country.

Comment: @DaleM as far as the definition of "law" I am assuming that we are speaking of the countable definition of law ("*a* law" in the question) which, in the US, refers to the definition implied in the constitution, namely that of bills, signatures, and overridden vetos.  In the phrase "common law" we are dealing with a non-countable sense.  There's no "law" that causes common-law marriages, for example, just a tenet or principle of common law.  "Law" in that sense is uncountable, and denotes the entire system of legal precedent, etc., that constitutes common law.